# How to handle drop-down list's selected changing?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp-classic

I have a little tag

```
 <select name="txtTK" >
<option value="None">---</option>
    <option value="Mat">Materials</option>
    <option value="Cate">Category</option>
    <option value="Cus">Customer</option>
    <option value="Work">Work</option>
<Option value="Em">Employee</Option>
 </select>
```

I want when i choose "Customer" option then the tag   will show up the 
the table of Custom. But the page does not reload.
I have no idea. Actually i tried w3c ajax but it seems not work with me.
Please give me an advice.
Thank in advance.

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: i really don't know why u asked me like that. Because all i need is add an table for each option of <select> tag. I am trying the simple task first so that i can solve the complicate task.

Comment: i think if we can't solve the simple then how to solve the hard??? Sorry for being rude due to my bad English.

Comment: "Give them the rod and do not give them the fish" is what my homeland said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your looking for is this [change()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)

Heres an example you can try:

### HTML:

```
<select class="target">
  <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".target").change(function(){
    alert("The value has been changed.");
  });
});
```

So all we are doing here is checking if the value has changed for the element within the class `.target`. If the value has changed then it will run the function.

Comment: Sorry but none of ur code work with me. But it gave me a hint. Thank a lot, my friends.

Comment: Please help me from now (yoroshiku onegaishimasu).

Comment: @user3024013 The code does work, I tested it. I wouldn't put code up that doesn't work lol.

Comment: Did you include: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery. Try like this.

```
<select name="select_user_type" id="select_user_type">
    <option>Select User</option>
    <option value="reg_farmar.php">Farmer</option>
    <option value="reg_expart.php">Expert</option>
    <option value="reg_supervisor.php">Supervisor</option>
    <option value="reg_coordinator.php">Coordinator</option>
    <option value="reg_officer.php">Officer</option>
    <option value="reg_manager.php">Manager</option>
    </select>
    <script>
       $('#select_user_type').change(function () {
       var str = "";

   $("select option:selected").each(function () {
     str += $(this).text() + " ";
     });           
     var str = String($(this).val());
     $('#div1').load(str);                     
     })
     .change();
</script>
```